# send current date only if box is checked

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a crud system in PHP and creating an approval section. I've create an approval page for the products which works great if the box is checked. But if its not and the person puts in the form, the date is still inputed. How can I have it only input the date if the box is checked?

Here is the form...

```
// if the form was submitted
if($_POST){

    $product->reviewed = $_POST['reviewed'];
    $product->review_date = $_POST['review_date'];
    // set product property values

    // update the product
    if($product->approve()){
        echo "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable'>";
            echo "Product approvals were set.";
        echo "</div>";
    }

    // if unable to update the product, tell the user
    else{
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'>";
        echo "Unable to approve product.";
        echo "</div>";
    }
}


?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?id={$id}");?>" method="post">
    <table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><?php echo $product->name; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Review</td>
            <td><?php 
                if (is_null($product->reviewed)){   
                    ?>  
                <div id="ck-button"><label><input type="checkbox" name="reviewed"  value="<?php echo $userRow['user_name'];?>" id="checkbox"/><span>Approve</span>
                    <input type='hidden' name='review_date' class='form-control' value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d h:i:sa"); ?>"/>
                </div>  </label>            

                <?php       ;
                }elseif (isset($product->reviewed)){
                    echo "<div id='approved-button'>" . $product->reviewed . ", " . $product->review_date . "</div>";

                }
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Set Approvals</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Here is the function in the Product class

```
    //approval for products
    function approve(){
        $query = "UPDATE
                    " . $this->table_name . "
                SET
                    reviewed = :reviewed,
                    review_date = :review_date

                WHERE
                    id = :id";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        $this->id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->id));  
        $this->reviewed=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->reviewed));
        $this->review_date=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->review_date));    

        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $this->id); 
        $stmt->bindParam(":reviewed", $this->reviewed);
        $stmt->bindParam(":review_date", $this->review_date);

        // execute the query
        if($stmt->execute()){
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }
```

Comment: In the second `<tr>`, your end tags are mismatched. You are closing the outer `<div>` before the `<label>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a checkbox element has been 'checked' in PHP you do the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['myCheckbox'])) { ... }
```

Instead, you have

```
if($_POST) { ... }
```

Which is what your problem seems to be if I am understanding your question correctly.

Comment: I'll be adding more approval buttons. I don't want it to not post anything at all of one of them isn't checked. I just don't want it to post the date unless the box is checked.

Comment: Or would you recommend adding another if above the other one.

Comment: If you want to use the other data and just conditionally set the checkboxed data then you can still use the same functionality as described above. When setting your values check and make sure that the checkboxes are checked. If they are, set the value, if they aren't don't set the value.

Comment: I tried adding this but it didn't work. Still adds the date.

`if(isset($_POST['reviewed'])){
 $product->review_date = $_POST['review_date'];
 $product->reviewed = $_POST['reviewed'];
 
}`

Comment: managed to get it working with this

`
if(isset($_POST['reviewed'])){
 $product->review_date = $_POST['review_date'];
 $product->reviewed = $_POST['reviewed'];
 
}elseif(!isset($_POST['reviewed'])){
 unset($_POST['review_date']);
 
}
`